# Use simplex method to solve linear programming problem

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The problem I am given is max $x_1 + 3x_2$ subject to $x_1 + x_2 \leq 5, 3x_1 - x_2 \geq -3, x_1,x_2 \geq 0$

The first step I took was to put this into standard form:
max $x_1 + 3x_2$ subject to $x_1 + x_2 + s_1 = 5, -3x_1 + x_2 +s_2 = 4, x_1,x_2, s_1, s_2 \geq 0$.  This yields matrices $ A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &1 &1 & 0 \\ -3 & 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $, $b = \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$, and $c = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Now, the way I was taught to do this is different than any example I've seen online so if you know of somewhere I could find similar examples that would be very helpful.

I now try to follow the formula given in my notes.

Let $k=1, s_1, s_2$ be basic and $x_1,x_2$ be nonbasic. then $x_B^1 = B^{-1}(b-Sx_s),B^T\pi = c_B,$ and $c_{N'} = c_{N} - A_{N}\pi$.  I'm not entirely sure what all of these things should be.  Mainly, $S$ and $x_s$.  I think $c_N, A_N$ represent the coefficients of the nonbasic variables in the above matrices, i.e. $A_N = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &1 \\ -3 & 1 \end{bmatrix} , c_N = \begin{bmatrix} 1  \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} $.  Could someone please clarify and help me work through this step and maybe the next one of $k=2$?

Thanks

Comment: A shortcut : Haven't you been said that, for 2 variables, you can draw the domains limited by straight lines $x_1+x_2=5$, $3x_1-x_2=-3$ intersecting in $(x_1^*,x_2^*)=(1/2,9/2)$, where the maximum is attained, the slope of the function to be maximized being favorable. Thus the answer is $x_1^*+3x_2^*=14$.

Comment: @JeanMarie We've never done that in class so I'm not sure if I can use it, but it is nice to know.  The majority of notes I'm finding online do exactly that.  Its frustrating that you can get the answer in seconds while I've been looking at this problem for hours and haven't made much headway